# Fix distance between image and text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the issue where I cant adjust the distance between an image and a text.

CSS:

```
.medarbetare-img {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    margin-top: 28px;
}
```

CODE:

```
 <div class="left">
    <div class="medarbetare-img" style="background:url(http://byggprojektoren.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Rinor2.jpg) center top no-repeat;"></div>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <br>
 <p style="font-size:12px;">RM
        <br>Konstruktör, VD,delägare
        <br> <a style="font-size:12px;" href="mailto:@byggprojektoren.se">@byggprojektoren.se</a>
        <br>0762 - 62 23 567</p>
</div>

    <p style="text-align:justify; font-size:12px; padding:10px 0;">Utbildad civilingenjör inom konstruktionsteknik. Under min studietid har jag arbetat som arbetsledare under tre somrar samt jobbat inom VDC på entreprenadföretaget NCC </p>
```

I tried adjusting the `margin-bottom: -25px`- but nothing happends, only on the mobile site. Does anyone have an idea why distance wont get smaller?

URL: http://byggprojektoren.se/om-byggprojektoren/

Comment: You have to set `.textwidget p { padding: 0; }`

Comment: like this: `.medarbetare-img {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    margin-top: 28px;
  .textwidget p { padding: 0; }
}` ? - I did not narrow the distance between the picture and the text under it.

Comment: You have to clarify what distance you want to reduce. If you want the distance between image and the text below it this addition would work.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately it did not change the distance at all? Should I maybe modify the padding: 0 to another number?

Comment: hm.. you are right, you have ether to put `.textwidget p { padding: 0 !important; }` or change the padding to the inline `p` rule.

Comment: How can i change the padding to the inline `p` rule? Thank you

Comment: You have to find this in your html code `<p style="text-align:justify; font-size:12px; padding:10px 0;"></p>`.

Comment: Yes, and what do I need to modify in there?

Comment: The obvious, padding to 0.

Comment: Still learning as you can see! But it works now, thank you mister.

Comment: Nice to hear that, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving to the `.left` class the `margin-bottom` attribute.

```
.left {
    margin-bottom: -28px;
}
```

Because the div with the class: `medarbatare-img` is in another div with the class of `left`.

Comment: hi, I tried `.medarbetare-img {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    margin-top: 28px;
  .left { margin-bottom: -28px; }
}`- But nothing happend?

Comment: What text you want to get closed to the div, the text in the left or the text under the image?

Comment: The text under the image.